# latex multicolumn formatting error

Tags: tables, pdftex, texmaker, multicolumn

Essentially I would like the word 'likelihood' to be in the fifth column of the fifth row. With the fourth column of the fifth row having no border except on it's right edge. How would i go about achieving that?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | p{2.5cm} | p{2.5cm} | p{2.5cm} | p{2.5cm} | p{2.5cm} |  } 
\hline
 Impact & High & Medium & High & Critical\\
\hline

\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}  & Medium & Low &  Medium & High\\
\cline{2-5}

\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & Low & Low & Low & Medium \\
\cline{2-5}

\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & Low & Medium & High \\
\cline{3-5}

\multicolumn{2}{c|} Likelihood & & \\
\cline{3-5}

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the lines

```
\multicolumn{2}{c|} Likelihood & & \\
\cline{3-5}
```

to

```
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{} & Likelihood\\
\cline{5-5}
```

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ | *{5}{p{2cm}|}  } 
\hline
 Impact & High & Medium & High & Critical\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}  & Medium & Low &  Medium & High\\
\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & Low & Low & Low & Medium \\
\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & Low & Medium & High \\
\cline{3-5}
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{} & Likelihood\\
\cline{5-5}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great answer, worked. Have a merry christmas my dude.